# How to investigate the surface integral $\iint_Sf(x,y,z)\,dS$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, multiple-integral

$$\iint_Sf(x,y,z)\,dS\,,$$ where $S$ is the part of graph $z=x^2+y^2$ below the plane $z=y$.

I am wondering what is the surface mean. I can not imagine it. If I use the polar coordinates, then what is the range of each variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersection of $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=y$ is $\left(y- \frac{1}{2} \right)^2+ x^2 = \frac{1}{4}$.
$$\underset{S}\iiint f(x,y,z)dS = \underset{\left(y- \frac{1}{2} \right)^2+ x^2 \leqslant \frac{1}{4}}\iint f(x,y,x^2+y^2)\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}dxdy$$

Comment: The *projection* of the intersection. Now how do you switch to polar coordinates?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin. I count it *obvious* on this level, not needing extra remarks. And why are you asking about polar coordinates?

Comment: Obviously wrong. Part of our job is to teach correct things. Re polar coordinates, did you bother to read the OP?

Comment: Obviously wrong consider yourself as oracle of correctness. Excessive nit-picking just prevents as studying, so learning -  not to interfere with learning is a minimum, helping to study is a maximum - so I understand teaching. We, obviously, don’t have a common job. Do you bother to see "if" in starting of sentence about polar coordinates? Here polar coordinates are double-edged sword and where to apply it - to region or to function heavily depends on $f$ integrand. And do you bother to read OP main concern about surface imagining and meaning? This is answered.

Comment: Thanks. So that means I can change in polar coordinates with $0\leq r \leq sin(\theta)$ and $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$?

Comment: @Tornado David. Yes, of course. This variant simplifies integrand, but not region. There is another possibility also: you can use something extended polar coordinates for region with $x=r \cos \phi$ and $y =\frac{1}{2} +r \sin \phi$ and obtain simplified region, but not integrand. So, decision, probably, depends on $f$ function.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!